# Creating an in memory rasterio Dataset from numpy array

Tags: numpy, rasterio, resampling

I am reading in a raster using rasterio, and then upsampling the raster as per the example in the documentation:

```py
def upsample_raster(raster):
    return raster.read(
        out_shape=(raster.height * 2, raster.width * 2, raster.count),
        resampling=resampling.bilinear,
    )
```

This seems to work fine, except that this method **returns the data in a numpy array**.

My current application workflow includes operations such as [masking](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/rasterio.mask.html#rasterio.mask.mask) which takes as input rasterio's `DatasetReader` class.

Thus, I am searching for a way to resample a raster and get the result as a `DatasetReader` or, without dumping the data to disk and re-opening the file, convert a numpy array into a valid `DatasetReader`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Note: You can use [rasterio.features.geometry_mask](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.features.html#rasterio.features.geometry_mask) to mask your numpy array without writing a dataset ([example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/448585/2856)).

Otherwise if you want to use [`rasterio.mask.mask`](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/rasterio.mask.html#rasterio.mask.mask), you can create a `DatasetReader` manually and you can use a [`MemoryFile`](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/memory-files.html#writing-memoryfiles) to avoid writing to disk.

You can re-use the metadata from the input raster in the `DatasetReader`, but you'll need to modify the `height` and `width` properties and the `transform`.  From [documentation](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/resampling.html):

> After these resolution changing operations, the dataset’s resolution and the resolution components of its affine transform property no longer apply to the new arrays.

In the example below note that:

1. I use a [`contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) so the `DatasetReader` and `MemoryFile` objects get cleaned up automatically. This is why I use `yield` not `return` in the function
2. I had to change the order of indexes in `raster.read` as arrays are `(band, row, col)` order not `(row, col, band)` like you used in your snippet.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager  

import rasterio
from rasterio import Affine, MemoryFile
from rasterio.enums import Resampling

# use context manager so DatasetReader and MemoryFile get cleaned up automatically
@contextmanager
def resample_raster(raster, scale=2):
    t = raster.transform

    # rescale the metadata
    transform = Affine(t.a / scale, t.b, t.c, t.d, t.e / scale, t.f)
    height = raster.height * scale
    width = raster.width * scale

    profile = raster.profile
    profile.update(transform=transform, driver='GTiff', height=height, width=width)

    data = raster.read( # Note changed order of indexes, arrays are band, row, col order not row, col, band
            out_shape=(raster.count, height, width),
            resampling=Resampling.bilinear,
        )

    with MemoryFile() as memfile:
        with memfile.open(**profile) as dataset: # Open as DatasetWriter
            dataset.write(data)
            del data

        with memfile.open() as dataset:  # Reopen as DatasetReader
            yield dataset  # Note yield not return     


with rasterio.open('path/to/raster') as src:
    with resample_raster(src) as resampled:
        print('Orig dims: {}, New dims: {}'.format(src.shape, resampled.shape))
        print(repr(resampled))
```

Output

```
Orig dims: (4103, 4682), New dims: (8206, 9364)
<open DatasetReader name='/vsimem/95befda0-2061-4294-982b-20e46f127066.' mode='r'>
```

Comment: Very helpful, thanks ! I just wonder if there is a typo and "profile = src.profile" in the resample() method should be "profile = raster.profile"?

Comment: Indeed, very helpful! Maybe also relevant: the implementation of rasterio.open() - [see this link](https://github.com/rasterio/rasterio/blob/master/rasterio/__init__.py#L196)

Answer (score 14):

I wrote a wrapper for `rasterio.mask.mask` that accepts numpy arrays as inputs.

```
def mask_raster_with_geometry(raster, transform, shapes, **kwargs):
    """Wrapper for rasterio.mask.mask to allow for in-memory processing.

    Docs: https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.mask.html

    Args:
        raster (numpy.ndarray): raster to be masked with dim: [H, W]
        transform (affine.Affine): the transform of the raster
        shapes, **kwargs: passed to rasterio.mask.mask

    Returns:
        masked: numpy.ndarray or numpy.ma.MaskedArray with dim: [H, W]
    """
    with rasterio.io.MemoryFile() as memfile:
        with memfile.open(
            driver='GTiff',
            height=raster.shape[0],
            width=raster.shape[1],
            count=1,
            dtype=raster.dtype,
            transform=transform,
        ) as dataset:
            dataset.write(raster, 1)
        with memfile.open() as dataset:
            output, _ = rasterio.mask.mask(dataset, shapes, **kwargs)
    return output.squeeze(0)
```

This is done via first writing to `memfile` and then reading from it before the function call to `rasterio.mask.mask()`. The `MemoryFile` will be discarded after exiting the `with` statement.

Unit test:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    'raster,transform,shapes,expected',
    [
        pytest.param(
            # the raster is positioned between x in (5, 8) and y in (-14, -10)
            np.ones((4, 3), dtype=np.float32),
            rasterio.transform.Affine(1, 0, 5, 0, -1, -10),
            # mask out two pixels
            # box params: xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax
            [shapely.geometry.box(6.1, -12.9, 6.9, -11.1)],
            np.array([
                [0, 0, 0],
                [0, 1, 0],
                [0, 1, 0],
                [0, 0, 0],
            ], dtype=np.float32),
        ),
    ],
)
def test_mask_raster_with_geometry(raster, transform, shapes, expected):
    np.testing.assert_array_equal(
        mask_raster_with_geometry(raster, transform, shapes),
        expected)
```

Comment: This is great! It did exactly what I needed it to. Thanks!

Comment: this should be pushed to rasterio

Comment: The `MEM` driver appears to work too, and it ~50% faster

Comment: @Andy do you have any example of using the MEM driver with rasterio?

Comment: @KyleBarron I think you literally replace `driver='GTiff'` with `driver='Mem'`, iirc

Comment: I was able to get a helpful example in rasterio discussions: https://github.com/rasterio/rasterio/discussions/2781