# Georeferencing of PNG and Convert to TIFF using Python

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, georeferencing, rasterio, png

I have a PNG image which I am trying to georeference using four corners of coordinate information of the defined input image.

When I am trying to convert PNG to TIFF, I am getting 3 bands (R,G,B) raster. Then I have copied the metadata from the original raster and tried to save it as GeoTIFF along with copied metadata using rasterio library.

In the final output, I am getting only one e band as R band. but I want all the bands in my GeoTIFF output.

Below, I have attached, input PNG and output GeoTIFF images. While converting PNG to GeoTIFF, the blue and black features are missing. only yellow is capturing.

Below is my code,

```
import rasterio as rio
import numpy as np

#Input png image, to convert as geotiff
img = rio.open('C:/Users/Documents/Study_Area_2.png')
img = img.read([1,2,3])
img = img.astype('uint16')

# Input image for coordinate reference
with rio.open('C:/Users/Study_Area_2_RGB.tif') as src:
    naip_data_ras = src.read()
    naip_meta = src.profile

#output images
with rio.open('C:/Users/Georeferenced.tif', 'w', **naip_meta) as dst:
    dst.write(img,[1,2,3])
```

Input Png image

[image]

Output GeoTIFF

[image]

Comment: What are you using to view the output image?

Comment: rasterio library

Comment: have you taken a look at this question? [Rasterio - save multiband raster to TIFF file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/329925/rasterio-save-multiband-raster-to-tiff-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**edit:** even more specific, the problem lies with `.astype(uint16)`. Without this conversion, it loads fine. Also `show(limg.read())` also works
**original:**
The problem lies with the `show(rio.open(georeferenced.tif))`. The data is saved properly, and when loaded all operations you would want to perform should work fine. if you're only interested in showing the image, you can `show(limg.read([1,2,3])`

Further, an (ugly) workaround would be to re-load and save the data. Then you can also resample so your rasters overlap (for calculations). When performed directly on the PNG, this crashed my kernel (sounds like a bug).
I also changed the arguments for the `rasterio.open('w')` to use the shape of your `img` in stead of the reference image in case they do not exactly match. optionally, you could maybe resample your georeferenced image, so

```
import rasterio as rio
from rasterio.enums import Resampling
from rasterio.plot import show

#Input png image, to convert as geotiff
img = rio.open('/path/to.png')
img = img.read([1,2,3])
img = img.astype('uint16')
show(img) #shows true color

# Input image for coordinate reference
with rio.open('/path/to/reference.tif') as naip:
    #open georeferenced.tif for writing
    with rio.open(
        'georeferenced.tif',
        'w',
        driver='GTiff',
        count=img.shape[0],
        height=img.shape[1],
        width=img.shape[2],
        dtype=img.dtype,
        crs=naip.crs,
        transform=naip.transform,
        ) as dst:
            dst.write(img)

with rio.open('georeferenced.tif') as limg:
        show(limg) #1 band only shows
        show(limg.read([1,2,3])) #shows true color
        #resample so pixels overlap with reference
        limg = limg.read(out_shape=(3,naip.shape[0],naip.shape[1]),
                         resampling=Resampling.nearest)
        with rio.open('resampled.tif','w', 
                     driver='GTiff',
                     count=limg.shape[0],
                     height=limg.shape[1],
                     width=limg.shape[2],
                     dtype=limg.dtype,
                     crs=naip.crs,
                     transform=naip.transform,
                     ) as dst:
            dst.write(limg)
```

The writing is a bit verbose, but a passing of `**naip.profile` does not work, since the count is different, unless your reference layer has the same number of bands. an alternative would be storing naip.profile, and then changing the count manually.