# Creating an in-memory raster with rasterio

Tags: rasterio

Note that this is not the same as [Creating an in memory rasterio Dataset from numpy array](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/329434/creating-an-in-memory-rasterio-dataset-from-numpy-array).

Currently I have a workflow which creates a "template raster" from which other rasters are derived. However, this template raster is written to disk, which is not very efficient:

```
import rasterio

rst = rasterio.open("test.tif", 'w+', driver='GTiff',
                    height=5, width=5,
                    count=1, dtype=rasterio.float32,
                    crs='+proj=utm +zone=36 +south +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,-0,-0,-0,0 +units=m +no_defs',
                    transform=rasterio.transform.from_origin(0, 0, 5, 5))
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to initialize this raster purely in memory but in such a way that I can still access its properties and methods like:

- `rst.index(0, 0)`
- `rst.meta`
- `rst.shape`

I am trying to use `MemoryFile`, but I can't find any examples of creating such a memory-based file directly, rather it is usually used for opening an existing disk file or a numpy array, like in the question I linked at the beginning.

Is there a way to be able to open a MemoryFile using the same parameters as `rasterio.open(...)`? So far the closest I can get is:

```
rst = rasterio.open("test.tif", 'w+', driver='GTiff',
                    height=5, width=5,
                    count=1, dtype=rasterio.float32,
                    crs='+proj=utm +zone=36 +south +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,-0,-0,-0,0 +units=m +no_defs',
                    transform=rasterio.transform.from_origin(0, 0, 5, 5))

profile = rst.profile

memfile = MemoryFile()
memfile.open(**profile)
```

But this still requires making a file on disk.

Comment: Have you tried creating the MemoryFile earlier and passing it instead of a filename to rasterio.open?

Comment: https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/issues/977 -> "Writing to MemoryFile" sounds appropriate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should have looked harder, it turns out it is just as simple as passing almost the same parameters to `memfile.open()`:

```
memfile = MemoryFile()
rst = memfile.open(driver='GTiff', height=5, width=5, count=1, dtype=rasterio.float32,
                   proj=utm +zone=36 +south +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,-0,-0,-0,0 +units=m +no_defs', transform=rasterio.transform.from_origin(0, 0, 5, 5)
```

It then behaves (as far as I can tell, just like a typical raster dataset object.

Comment: `show(rasterio.open(rst))`does not work. @wfgeo @bugmenot123 , would you know how to display/plot the raster natively in Rasterio? I would like to avoid the option of passing the rasterio.open(rst).read() array, and its extents, to plt.imshow.