# Rasterio forces me to write intermediate files which I don't need

Tags: python, rasterio

I would like to first merge rasters and then clip the resulting raster using `geopandas` and `rasterio`. Here's what I came up with so far:

```
import rasterio
import glob
from rasterio import merge
from rasterio import mask
import geopandas

files = glob.glob("*.tif")
datasets = []

for file in files:
    ds = rasterio.open(file)
    meta = ds.meta.copy()
    datasets.append(ds)

out_data, out_transform = merge.merge(datasets)

meta["count"] = out_data.shape[0]
meta["height"] = out_data.shape[1]
meta["width"] = out_data.shape[2]
meta["transform"] = out_transform

for ds in datasets:
    ds.close()

with rasterio.open("merged.tif", "w", **meta) as ds:
    ds.write(out_data)

province = geopandas.read_file("province.shp")

with rasterio.open("merged.tif") as ds:
    out_data, out_transform = mask.mask(ds, shapes=province.geometry)

with rasterio.open("province.tif", "w", **meta) as ds:
    ds.write(out_data)
```

I opened up the result and it looks correct on QGIS.

What bugs me is that I have to write an intermediate file called `merged.tif` when I don't really need it in my workflow. All I care about is `province.tif`, yet `rasterio`s heavy reliance on Python context managers and open file objects forces me to write this file.

I saw that rasterio also proposes a `MemoryFile` object which would in theory allow me to skip writing this file on my physical hard disk, but I'm nevertheless still required to use a python context manager, which just doesn't seem very pythonic and smells like poor design on the part of `rasterio`.

Is there any other alternative or workaround? Are there any higher level or better designed libraries to work with gridded geospatial data using python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`rasterio.features.geometry_mask`](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.features.html#rasterio.features.geometry_mask) to mask your numpy array without writing a dataset.

```
import rasterio as rio
import glob
from rasterio import features
from rasterio import merge
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np

files = glob.glob("*.tif")
datasets = []

for file in files:
    ds = rio.open(file)
    datasets.append(ds)

    meta = ds.meta.copy()
    datasets.append(ds)

out_data, out_transform = merge.merge(datasets)

meta["count"] = out_data.shape[0]
meta["height"] = out_data.shape[1]
meta["width"] = out_data.shape[2]
meta["transform"] = out_transform

for ds in datasets:
    ds.close()

province = gpd.read_file("province.shp")

mask = features.geometry_mask(
            province.geometry,
            out_shape=out_data.shape[1:],
            transform=out_transform,
            all_touched=False,
            invert=True)

with rio.open("province.tif", "w", **meta) as ds:
    ds.write(np.ma.MaskedArray(out_data, mask))
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @user32882 did this [answer your question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) or is there something that I could improve in my answer?

Comment: @user32882 I never got around to actually testing this but I will assume your answer is correct.